# Doorkeeper: How to know when a grant is created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, oauth, doorkeeper

I would like to create a membership record when a user grants access to an app.

Does Doorkeeper have any event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was to use a rails observer:

> Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails-observers'
```

> app/models/doorkeeper/access_token_observer.rb:

```
class Doorkeeper::AccessTokenObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_create(access_token)
    # do stuff with:
    # access_token.application_id
    # access_token.resource_owner_id
  end
end
```